# How to use feathers client with webpack

Tags: webpack, feathersjs

According to the docs, I can use `feathers/client` but when I try

let feathers = require('feathers/client');
let app = feathers();

which is compiled by webpack, I get

```
./~/feathers/package.json
Module parse failed: /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/expenses-app/node_modules/feathers/package.json Unexpected token (2:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:9)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/expenses-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:918:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/expenses-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1480:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/expenses-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1459:73)
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their client contains a line like this:

```
createApplication.version = require('../../package.json').version;
```

That will make webpack to process the *package.json* of their project. This will fail unless you have set up [json-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader).